# Spark Scala - Process files in parallel and get dataframe for each file

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have thousands of large files to process.
I'm trying to read these files in parallel, and then convert each of them to DataFrame so that I can aggregate data and extract numerical features etc.

I tried sc.wholeTextFiles() which gives us file name and content tuple RDD, but i'm not allowed to use sparkContext/sqlContext to create dataframe which in the RDD map.

```
val allFiles = sc.wholeTextFiles(inputDir)
val rows = allFiles.map {
  case (filename, content) => {
    val s = content.split("\n")
    // Convert the content to RDD and dataframe later
    //val r = sc.parallelize(s); <-- Serialization Error
  }
}
```

Access sc about throws serialization error as we are not supposed to sc to tasks.

I also considered:

```
val input = sc.textFile(inputDir)
input.mapPartitions(iter => <process partition data>)
```

But with above approach, when files are large it would split into several partitions and i loose ability to process file as a "whole"

So is there any other option where I can process whole files in parallel, convert each of the dataframe etc?

Comment: Why exactly do you want that? If files are small enough to be accessed with `wholeTextFiles` then using `DataFrame` per file doesn't make much sense.

Comment: I'm dealing with flight sensor data, i get each flight data in a file. I need to perform some feature extraction and ML on each of them, hence was thinking converting each of them to a DataFrame would be convenient. So instead are you suggesting me to load all the files using sc.textfiles() and then group by etc?

Comment: For starters I would consider processing data globally and only keeping track of the input. I assume you want to apply the same pipeline for all files.